# check if nginx pseudo streaming is working

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, mp4, pseudo-streaming

i have nginx 1.9 version installed, and enabled mp4 ngx_http_mp4 modules,and i configured the setting below.

```
location /video/ {
mp4;
mp4_buffer_size       1m;
mp4_max_buffer_size   5m;
mp4_limit_rate        on;
mp4_limit_rate_after  30s; 
}
```

but when i use jwplayer to play the mp4 file and checking it using live-http-header, when i jump to different time: the data shows without start parameter. eg."GET /data/mytest.mp4 HTTP/1.1", which i supposed it should be "GET /data/15099.mp4?start=xxx HTTP/1.1"
so is my ngx_http_mp4 working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about jwplayer but I did this test to check if ngx_http_mp4 is working at all:

http://yoursite.com/yourvideo.mp4?start=10

When your movie start from the beginning it's not working. It should start at 10sec.